# $X,Y \sim $iid $\operatorname{Exp}(\lambda),\ P(X \le t, X + Y > t)$?

Tags: probability

$X$ and $Y$ are 2 identical exponentially distributed independent random variables.

$X,Y \sim$ iid $\operatorname{Exp}(\lambda)$

What's the following probability?

$$P(X \le t, X + Y > t)$$

I cannot seem to find the answer by manipulating the probability appropriately, but I think the answer has to be $\lambda  t \operatorname{exp}(-\lambda t)$ based on the next subquestion in my homework that I could answer. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean the probability that $X\le t\textbf{ and }X+Y>t$ or might you mean the conditional probability that $X\le t$ given that $X+Y>t$? ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 4):

Draw the line (1), $x=t$, and the line (2), $x+y=t$. We want the probability that $(X,Y)$ lands in the region $K$ to the left of line (1) and above line (2). This probability is the integral of the joint density over $K$. It is easiest to integrate first with respect to $y$. Our probability is
$$\int_{x=0}^t\lambda e^{-\lambda x}\left(\int_{y=t-x}^\infty \lambda e^{-\lambda y} \,dy                 \right)\,dx.$$
The first integration is easy, and the second one easier.

Comment: This works even when both $X$ and $Y$ have different parameters right?